# Deadlocks caused due to async await [MySQL Database]

Tags: c#, mysql, multithreading, entity-framework, async-await

I have the below async method which deletes and insert records to MySQL Database

```
public async Task<Res> myNewFunc(int id, IEnumerable<Sample> obs)
{      
    using (var t = DbConnection.GetTransaction())
    {
        await DbConnection.DeleteMany<M1>().Where(x.Id == id).ExecuteAsync();
        foreach (var ob in obs)
        {
            await DbConnection.InsertAsync(ob);
        }
        t.Complete();
    }
}
```

Method which calls myNewFunc() :

```
public async Task<T> method()
{
    //...
    //...
    var response = await DAL.myNewFunc(id, obs);
}
```

The async method is accessed using a foreach loop.

```
foreach(var num in nums)
{
    method();
}
```

I am facing a dead lock problem with MySQL using the above code.

Comment: The `foreach` looks strange; you are iterating over `nums` but not using the value. You are calling `method()` without awaiting it or storing the task for awaiting later.

Comment: You only get Deadlocks if the scope of a lock expands halfway through. It is important to agressively lock any resource you *might* need, not just the ones you know for certain you will need. Without seeing the SQL it is really hard to tell what might happen on the DB side.

Comment: Agree with @Christopher, You should look at the database and find the actual cause of the deadlock. I'm not familiar with troubleshooting deadlocks in MySql but a quick search suggests that you can find the actual statements causing the problem.

Comment: Since the foreach has no wait in it, it's going to run through all iterations without stopping/pausing/waiting. This will cause X number of 'method' calls to be fired back to back. Each of those will call myNewFunc immediately and wait. This then calls your DeleteMany and waits. But the calls to myNewFunc and DeleteMany aren't aware of each other, and if they're trying to delete things in the same table you're gonna get a deadlock, as you're seeing. This will propagate out with triggers and other tables called in that delete.

Comment: what about `t.commit()` instead of complete?

Comment: This is and always was a SQL issue. Single discrete one line DML statemetns are wrapped into a transaction and lock implicitly. You must have something way more complex then that to ever get a deadlock.

Comment: @PHPMODE Your best bet if you can't control the foreach, is to try to better handle it on the SQL side. Stored procs, limit the triggers involved in those, use: with (NOLOCK) on any selects in there. Try to atomize the SQL side more, so tables don't get locked doing simple inserts/deletes while other longer running things happen later in the script. Check indexes for the effected tables, to try and help the queries run faster. When doing "updates" like this, try to keep those sections as small and self contained as possible.

Comment: @PHPMODE You can end up with phantom rows, if you're not careful. You could start an insert in one thread, do a read in another, and then if your insert thread fails and rolls back, you're read will still have the record (it won't be in the DB) but any operations running on the read set will see a row that no longer exists in your DB (because that transaction failed and was aborted). If you manage your reads, and how you act on that data you can work around that.

Answer (score -1):

Because you aren't awaiting in the last for loop, it is going to spin up threads for all of those and run all of those at the same time in parallel.  If you have a lot of data here, they will all be fighting for the same resources.  You end up creating transactions in each case and then delete multiple records from the table.  However, that may not be the true underlying problem.  On all of your ExecuteAsync calls, you don't do .ConfigureAwait(false).  This means after running each statement, it waits until it can resume its work on the original thread, in this case the UI thread.  I don't know what you do after the for loop, but its possible this thread never lets go, so none of these db calls can ever come back and you get deadlocks.

Two ways you can try to fix this:

1. each Async() call needs to be Async().ConfigureAwait(false).  If it is really the UI thread being locked, this might fix it.
2. In the last for loop, you need to wait for each one instead because maybe the DB Resources are getting all tied up.  Use this code instead:

```
foreach(var num in nums)
{
    method().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```

This will only process one at a time.  For #2, you might need to do #1 as well.